# Redirect Port via iptables on AWS EC2 Ubuntu instance

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, iptables

I have a running AWS EC2 instance on an Ubuntu machine running a Nodejs server.
Everything works fine then opening the website via its public ip on port 3000 likes this:

`http://XX.XXX.XXX.XXX:3000`

Now I want to redirect all requests from port 80 to this port 3000 via iptables like described in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WxhFq64FQzA via

`sudo iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 3000`.

Unfortunately I am getting this error: http://prntscr.com/lja6hx when opening the site like this: `http://XX.XXX.XXX.XXX` (without port 3000 specified)

P.S.: I'm not really sure if my approach is correct. I am open to other ways of achieving a redirect from port 80 (http) to port 3000

---

As @Vorsprung suggested I should use an Application Load Balancer. I did this but it's still not working. Here is my setup:

My Application Load Balancer Listener
[image: Application Load Balancer Listener]

The Target Group I'm forwarding to in my ALB
[image: Target Group Description]
[image: Target Group Targets]

My hosted zone (I've added the alias for the ALB here)
[image: Hosted zone A record]

Please let me know if something is missing

Comment: Are you using a Framework (Express?) for your Node server? If so, you can just instruct it to listen on port 80 rather than port 3000. No redirect required. Example: https://expressjs.com/en/starter/hello-world.html

Comment: To run on port 80 you’d need to run as a privileged user. Try prefixing your command with “sudo”

Comment: I've actually tried this, but I still get the following error: http://prntscr.com/ljfkb1

Comment: Turn on evaluate health and ensure that your have a GET url that just returns a 200 for it.  Then you can see if the ALB can see the EC2.  I would normally not use the public ip on the EC2 for ALB->EC2 communications, I'd use the private VPC address.  But if you do this then make sure that there is a security group rule allowing the ALB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. either use nginx see https://nodebb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuring/proxies/nginx.html
   or
2. you are on AWS!  Use an ALB.. see  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/application-load-balancer-tutorials.html

Comment: I've tried to setup an ALB but it's still not working (I added more details to my question)